# Excel VBA to input formula followed by text into cell or cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, text, formula, cell

I have the count working fine as below:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C:R[-1]C)"
```

I want the cell to have the count followed by the word "Schemes"

I have tried

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C:R[-1]C)"  & "Schemes"
```

but fails. I am not sure about the quototation marks. I also tried using + and AND but also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try it in this way:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C:R[-1]C)&"" Schemes"""
```

The concatenation character (`&`) must be inside the formula string and any double quotes must be doubled when the code writes the formula. I also thought that a space must be let between the formula result and the ending string...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `With` and two lines:

```
With Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C:R[-1]C)"
.Value = .Value & "Schemes"
End With
```